# redirect page before insert in grocery crud

Tags: php, grocery-crud

I want to redirect page before insert when some condition happened and the page reloaded successfully in firebug.

my code :

```
$crud->callback_before_insert(array($this,'callback_function'));
```

the function :

```
$getRow1= $this->db->where('nationalityID',$getRow->id)->get('table_name')->row();

$data = array('courseID'=>$courseID,'userID'=>$getRow1->id);
$insert= $this->db->insert('table_name1',$data);

if($insert) {
    $newlink =  base_url()."admin/control_trainee_courses/data/". $courseID;
    echo "<script>" . "window.location = '$newlink';</script>";

    // or using   redirect(base_url()."index.php/admin/control_trainee_courses/data/".$courseID ;
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>top.location.href='/index.php/';</SCRIPT>");
exit();
```

It will end code execution, so insert will not occur.

Also, make sure that you are redirecting to the same domain, or browser will prevent redirection.

Answer (score -1):

and you can use URl Helper and Redirect

```
redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
```